# Is there a way to use docx4j library to convert doc format documents?

Tags: doc, docx4j

I want to read doc format using docx4j. wondering if there's away or a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LibreOffice to convert binary doc to docx, and invoke it via JODConverter.

See [open-rtf-with-docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/open-rtf-with-docx4j-t2067.html) for more on JODConverter.

Comment: How can we do it in pure java?